# Playstore error: App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols

Tags: android-studio, flutter, google-play

When I want to release a new flutter app bundle to the Playstore. I get this error:
"This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug."
I can't find any way to fix this. I'm new with flutter and releasing app's and getting a bit desperate...
Any help would be fantastic.

When I add "android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'" (on line 1) to the app/build.gradle as suggested in https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#native-crash-symbolization. I get This error in the Android studio terminal. I use this command "flutter build appbundle".

Error in Terminal:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\filip\AndroidStudioProjects\ehbo\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                         4,3s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: It seems you need to upload deobfuscation / symbolication file . check below link:  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en

Comment: It's just beta problems, this functionality is not in stable gradle release yet, only in 4.1
So looks like Play console beta is for android studio beta now.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Before you can upload debug symbols files, you must be using Android Gradle plugin version 4.1 or higher.

Looks like it will come only with Android Studio 4.1, because I can only get Gradle 4.0.0 automatically now.

So I suggest you to return classic Play console and it will let you through :)

**UPDATE:**
So just use an updated Gradle and add NDK debug symbols to the build now

Comment: Dang, I think you're right. I can also go only up to 4.0 with Android Studio 4.0.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try it with the classic Play console

Comment: YES! It worked (I used the classic Play Console). Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think so, there will be some changes that we need to do in the future. What if I want to the new Play Console?

Comment: @PratikButani then you need to get Gradle plugin 4.1 which is probably available with some Android Studio 4.1 beta program now. Later when it is released, it will be available as default

Comment: Added a new description in the post below. The setup is right, but looks like Flutter team needs to update some building things

Comment: Almost one year later, you must to use the new Play Console, so, turning back to the "classic console" isn't a option.

Comment: It also needs to be the gradle plugin lower than 4.2.0

Answer (score 225):

Reproduce the next steps and this warning will disappear.

1. Go to
   `[YOUR_PROJECT]\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib`

> For some the path might be `[YOUR_PROJECT]\app\build\....` and not  `[YOUR_PROJECT]\build\app\....` like mentioned above.

Note that 3 folders exist inside

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi-v7a
- x86_64

2. Select these 3 folders and create a .zip file. The name doesn't matter.

[PLEASE NOTE THAT I HAVEN'T COMPRESSED THE ./lib FOLDER]

3. Upload this new *.zip file as a Symbol File.

.

The newest update, for us (8-Nov 2023) the folder exists in [YOUR_PROJECT]\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib

Comment: For anyone wondering how to upload the Symbols file ... https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en#zippy=%2Cupload-files-using-play-console

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Silly me thought that the *.symbols files were what needed to be uploaded for the "Native debug symbols" and not a zip of folders containing *.so files.

Comment: I'm using react native. I could not find merged_native_libs folder !! this is the path I tried : android/app/build/intermediates

Comment: nice, flutter should add compressed file with easy access jejej

Comment: For me the folder is actually at: [YOUR_PROJECT]\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib

Comment: I did that but it told me it contains MACoS files and only Android is supported, any Idea what to do? I am using macos

Comment: To prevent macOS files in the zip, use terminal instead:
1. `cd you_project_path/build/app/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/productionRelease/out/lib`
2. `rm .DS_Store`
3. `zip -r symbols.zip .`

And for anyone getting errors not accepting the .so files from this directory use build/app/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/productionRelease/out/lib instead.

Comment: So.. do I need to do this every time?

Comment: @Dara Java Welcome to flutter.

Comment: This same lib folder is also present within the .aab bundle itself. Change the .aab extension to .zip and extract it, then find it under the `base/` directory.

Useful if you're running the builds in CI/CD and it only outputs the bundle but not the intermediate artifacts.

Answer (score 76):

If talking about Flutter, looks like the Flutter team needs to change some source files for the NDK, because it does not see where from to generate debug symbols.

Here is an issue thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60240

Setup steps are so:

- Pre-condition: Intall Android studio 4.1+ and Gradle 4.1+

1. Install NDK (Side by Side) in SDK manager
   [image]
2. Write path to NDK in local.properties
   [image]
3. Add in app/build.gradle (last line) `android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'`
   [image]

Comment: I followed the same I get this, 
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ndk' for BuildType_Decorated{name=release,

Comment: @MSaudi See this link - I had the same problem. It was resolved after upgrading my gradle version. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63436935/7015661

Comment: `ndk.dir` is [depreciated](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio#4-0-0-ndk-dir)

Comment: Is this option for Flutter apps better than compressing the \build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib symbols? Using the NDK is automatic yeah, but the symbols produced by the NDK seems to be much much smaller than the symbols located in the mencioned folder. For my app, NDK size was 5kB and merged_native_libs was 12MB

Comment: @Bugzilla, why is smaller not preferred?

Comment: Why last line tho?

Answer (score 27):

The Answer was given by [Shakle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6077009/shakle) will be not useful as per the following message on Play Console.

> The old version of Play Console will be discontinued from November 2,
> 2020 You’re already using the new Play Console, so you don’t need to
> do anything. A few features are going away if you want to check them
> one last time.

It's just a warning, nothing else. Just go ahead.

If you don't want any warning, Go to this link and follow the steps:

**https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en**

You can use the new version of the **play store** as it is.

Answer (score 25):

you can make these zip file by go to `build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib` inside your Flutter project

and compress the folders into `symbols.zip`, now upload it into the google play console

Comment: after you get the .zip, where in google play can you upload this file please?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en#zippy=%2Cupload-files-using-play-console%2Cupload-files-using-the-google-play-developer-api

Comment: What exactly are you ziping ? .so files ? something else ?

Comment: everything inside the lib

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem.
What really helped me:

1. Make sure your Android Gradle plugin version is 4.1 or later.
2. Install NDK (Side by Side) in SDK manager.
3. Install CMake in SDK manager.
4. Add

```
    ndkVersion <ndkVersion>
    ndk {
      debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
    }
```

to app/build.gradle

My final `build.gradle`:

```
...
android {
  compileSdkVersion 30
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 28
    versionName "1.0.59"
    ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"
    ndk {
      debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
  }
}
...
```

I hope this will help you and save you time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To make this work in vsCode, I had to add the now deprecated option
ndk.dir=/path/to/ndk
in the local.properties file.

Comment: ndkVersion "23.1.7779620" this or it can be anything?

Comment: @DragonFire the number you add has to match the version you installed (via sdk manager)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to solve this warning error:
This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. Make sure also to install CMake

This will happen if your gradle version is higher than 4.0
Place this code into your `build.gradle` file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.myproject'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    ndk {
        debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rishav did you manage to solve it in React Native?

Comment: @LawrenceMacharia No. I realized that I don't care and everything is meaningless.

Comment: this solution worked for me with React-Native, but for my case, I had to install CMake and update my NDK to version 23.0.7599858, then I updated it on build.gradle(app) and finally followed this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367767/6674314

Comment: @acuriousguy solution worked for me with React Native as well. Make sure to install CMake: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#kts and set the debugSymbolLevel to `FULL` instead of `SYMBOL_TABLE`

Comment: @LawrenceMacharia In my case, for React Native, I had to manually zip up these files here: app/build/merged_native_libs/myAppRelease/out/lib and upload Native Debug Symbols - after moving back to the "Edit Release" step, and then tapping "Review Release" the error went away!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating and uploading zip files, you can include the following to your `app\build.gradle` file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug { 
        // This is just here for local testing and is optional.
        firebaseCrashlytics { 
            nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            unstrippedNativeLibsDir file("build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib")
        }
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
        }
    }
    release {
        // ..
        firebaseCrashlytics { // Insert this
            nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true 
            unstrippedNativeLibsDir file("build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib")
        }
        ndk {
            // replace with 'FULL' if you need more info,
            // but note that it will increase the file size of your appbundle dramatically.
            debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some documentation for reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports#upload-symbols-external-dependencies

And if you're unclear about how to set up automatic uploading of native symbols, try adding this:

```
buildTypes { ... } // Your build types from the above snippet.

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('assemble') && task.name != "assembleReleaseAndroidTest"
            && task.name != "assembleDebugAndroidTest") {
        String taskName = "uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile" + task.name.substring('assemble'.length())
        task.finalizedBy taskName
        doFirst {
            println "Running Gradle task '$taskName'..."
        }
    }
}
```

More info for building gradle tasks here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

Also, ensure that you have NDK and CMAKE installed in your IDE's SDK Manager.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Simple approach, go to \build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib , you will find 3/4 folders , zip those , upload this ZIP from release option ( upload Symbol File ). Warning will be gone after bundle review.

Answer (score 3):

I just upgraded ndk from 21.4.7075529 to 22.1.7171670, and now I get the debug symbols.

I'm using com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1 and React Natvive 0.69 BTW.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I've spent almost an entire day on this problem! 

Thank you for posting - that helped me.

Answer (score 2):

For fixing it in the Visual Studio Code: you should first download
the NDK from the android's website.

- Extract the zip file to a folder named `ndk` and place it under your - already installed - Android SDK folder. Like this: `Android/sdk/ndk`
- Then open `app/build.gradle`.
- Under the `Android` section. Add `ndkPath`  property as follows: `ndkPath = <ndk-dir>`

[app/build.gradle ndkPath property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG2kf.png)

- At the end of `app/build.gradle` add `android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'full'`
- The next appbundle, built by `flutter build appbundle` command should not give any errors on the play store about native debug symbols.

a more thorough explanation is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60240#issuecomment-917321657)

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue.

Possible solutions:

1. Use the Google classic Play console
2. Gradle 4.1 is now released with Android Studio 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Flutter to build native debug symbols using Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 4.1.0, installing corresponding NDK version and adding the appropriate config to `android/app/build.gradle` on macOS *(but it should also work on Windows/Linux)*.

0. *Optional: Run `flutter build appbundle` and take note of the `.aab` file size*
1. Check what version of AGP you're using in `android/build.gradle` by looking in dependencies e.g. `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` is `4.1.0`
2. Check which version of NDK you need. Assuming your AGP is `4.1.0` the NDK version you want to install is `21.1.6352462` *(for other AGP versions check mappings [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#default-ndk-per-agp))*
3. [Install specific NDK version using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#specific-version). Alternatively you can use `sdkmanager` and the CLI: `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.1.6352462"`
4. In `android/app/build.gradle`, under `android.defaultConfig` add `ndk { debugSymbolLevel 'FULL' }` aka set [`android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633#upload_file&zippy=%2Cupload-files-using-play-console%2Cmy-app-contains-both-native-and-java-code-can-i-upload-both-a-native-symbolication-file-and-a-java-deobfuscation-file%2Cnative-generate-a-debug-symbols-file)  as per [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633#upload_file&zippy=%2Cupload-files-using-play-console%2Cmy-app-contains-both-native-and-java-code-can-i-upload-both-a-native-symbolication-file-and-a-java-deobfuscation-file%2Cnative-generate-a-debug-symbols-file)
5. Run `flutter build appbundle`. The `.aab` should now contain native debug symbols and be larger than the previous build in step 0

*Troubleshooting: If you get any errors around CMake I didn't explicitly install it but you might need to, especially if you're using Windows, and [you can do so using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#default-version).*

Answer (score -1):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATUOX.png)

My issue was this:

> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.

Fix successfully just upload native debug symbols from the image reference directory shown.

Comment: Hi Jamshed, thanks for taking the time to post, however, your answer is exactly the same as the most upvoted answer.