# How to publish native code symbols to Google Play console?

Tags: android, google-play, native, debug-symbols, android-app-bundle

I am trying to publish an Android application to Google Play and getting a warning:

```
This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. 
We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.
```

I found in [one documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#android_gradle_plugin_version_41_or_later), that I should add

```
android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = { SYMBOL_TABLE | FULL }
```

line to `build.gradle` file and in [another documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features?hl=ru#how_to_upload_debug_symbols_files), tha I should add

```
android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
```

line to `build.gradle` file.

Which one is correct?

Anyway, neither is working.

If I add the line (as is) to `build.gradle` (literally following the documentation), I am getting `Gradle` errors that it can't find `ndk` or `debugSymbolLevel` names.

If I add the line (as is) to `gradle.properties`, than it has no effect: `aab` file appears having the same size and the warning persists.

How to accomplish?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62574090/504477. It could be a Gradle version issue.

Answer (score 11):

Both options will work. If you use `android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel` it will apply it to all build types (i.e., both debug and release builds). On the other hand, if you use `android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel` it will apply only to your release build.

These options have to be added into your `app/build.gradle` file, which would look a bit like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.foo'
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 42
        versionName "4.0.2"
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
        }
    }
    // Rest of the file
}
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Alberto, I followed your suggestion but unfortunately Play Console still fail in found ing debug symbol file inside the AAB. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: same here, don't know why. Really upset now

Comment: for me it only worked when I give 'symbol_table' in small case.