# NDK at ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, build.gradle

I have updated Android Studio to 4.1 in Macbook but not able to run app after updating. It is giving following error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
NDK at ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file
```

and don't forget to mention  latest ndk version if you seleted
android{

```
 ndkVersion: '25.1.8937393'
```

}

Comment: just remove ndk folder and try ( User/Android/Sdk/Ndk )

Answer (score 101, accepted):

After specifying ndk version in `build.gradle` file it is working

```
android {
        ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
    }
```

And inside `local.properties` remove the following since it's deprecated and also conflicts with path:

```
ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

Comment: Happened to me as well, but this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: On Android Studio 4.1

Comment: Please check your NDK version which you have installed.

Comment: The `ndk.dir` in the `local.properties` will work fine for the Gradle Plugin version < 4.1.0 and the Gradle version < 6.5. But, Gradle will complain once you start to use the latest versions.   https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: I had to put full path to ndk including version:
"ndk.dir=[...]\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\21.3.6528147"

Comment: I see the NDK dirs (22.0.7026061 and 21.1.6352462) **have** `source.properties`. None of the remedies in this answer worked for me. I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 on Mac OS 11.1.

Comment: I have tried it and it worked. But when I upload the apk to play store it shows a warning ... "This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug". How does this affect my app & how to solve it?

Comment: @KrishnaMeena this worked for me, but when i upload apk to google play console it shows like this - https://i.imgur.com/BOQzU3Q.png. How to solve this.

Comment: @mad_lad Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568757/playstore-error-app-bundle-contains-native-code-and-youve-not-uploaded-debug

Comment: updating build.gradle fix my issue

Comment: It worked for me. I was using NDK version (23.1.7779620).

Answer (score 72):

I had the same issue and solve it :
Go to SDK location find NDK folder and check the folders if one of them is empty or corrupted delete it and let the android studio use the latest version you have.

Comment: That was the working one. By doing this IDE is auto selecting the last one. It was looking into an empty folder so ofc it couldn't find any source.properties file. Thx !

Comment: This usually occurs when you cancel the build while it's installing a NDK, you're left with a corrupt/empty folder.

Comment: Yes this worked for me, the ndk-bundle directory was empty so I removed it and voila, everything worked!

Comment: Thanks, for me I had the following structure:

sdk -> ndk -> 21.1.6352462 -> .installer and  sdk -> ndk -> 21.1.6352462 -> 24.0.8215888 -> build, ...

So I used corrupted  `21.1.6352462`, change to `24.0.8215888` worked for me

Comment: This should be voted as the correct answer

Answer (score 40):

I had this error in Flutter.

my solution:

copy file `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\source.properties`

to

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle`

Ready!

Comment: There is ndk-bundle folder. However your answer helped as I copied the source.properties from 22.1.7171670 to the folder next to it 21.1.6352462 since it was mentioned in the error. Then everything worked

Comment: This is really a strange solution, but I will like to register my thank you - it works perfectly for me!

Comment: This too worked to me, I copied the source.properties to their parent folder, and the build was successful.

Comment: Thanks, this is much better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 33):

`File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> "Android NDK Location"`
And click "Download" Android NDK. The problem will be solved after downloaded.
[image]

Comment: somehow it can't click download. must manually add on local.properties.

Comment: I downloaded it for a first time. Right away I checked the path was not there and the "download" link was now disabled. But the NDK was indeed installed here (Windows): C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\22.0.7026061. I just needed to add this path in the file named local.properties (which is in the root of your android project, i.e: path_to_your_project/android/), backslashes escaped, just as the path for sdk.dir

Comment: What if that donload button doesnt show up

Comment: I downloaded ndk version that GitHub repo needs and the problem was solved. thank you.

Answer (score 28):

For **Android studio 4.1.1+** (`gradle-plugin`: 4.1.1 or above) use **`ndkVersion`**

> **No** `ndk.dir` at `local.properties`. If there is, remove it

build.gradle (module)

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
     // ...
     ndkVersion = "21.1.6352462"
  }
}
```

**Note**: The specified version must exist at `$SDK/ndk` folder.

Comment: This also works for Flutter. This is the build.gradle inside App. So the directory structure is android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 12):

For me, this issue occurred after I upgraded to Android Studio 4.1. To fix this, I had to explicitly pass the path of my `NDK` directory in my project's `local.properties` file. It can be done by adding this line in `local.properties`.

```
ndk.dir={Path to Android NDK directory}
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case I don't have ndk dir in the local.properties file and also didn't add ndk version in the build.gradle. I just simply deleted the ndk-bundle folder in the android sdk folder. and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

add ndkversion[image: ndk.dir=C:\Users\Hasif\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670]

```
ndk.dir=C:\\Users\\Hasif\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing the same problem from a few weeks and I had tried my best but didn't work. Then I downloaded NDK using android studio.

[Screenshot of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4KQf.png)

After downloading the NDK also not resolved my problem. Then I visited the SDK folder and found NDK and NDK-bundle. As I know the two folders have the same properties.

I had copied the source.properties file from the NDK \ 23.1.7779620 and pasted it into the NDK-Bundle folder.

[Screenshot of source.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFkIR.png)

It is working perfectly.

You should also try...

Comment: "You should also try ..." Try what ? Can you add the missing part ? :)

Comment: @Elikill58 Try what he mentioned above. Copy `source.properties` from ndk to ndk-bundle. This worked for me. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure about other cases but in my case, i facing the same issue

> NDK at D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file

And by deleting ndk-bundle folder and then rebuilding the project solved my issue
Hope anyone else gets this helpful

Comment: Solved for me as well.

Comment: solved for me, Thanks @Zahid Iqbal

Answer (score 6):

This is random error from AS, which is encountered by few developers.

Most likely, you don't have NDK linked in your Android Studio.

I would suggest,

In your Android Studio, Go to File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Under "Android NDK Location", click on "Download" Android NDK

Wait for download and re-build the project. Cheers.

Comment: after download ndk you need to add ndk location link to local.properties file like this: 

ndk.dir=/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

Comment: Brillant! Had this problem after updating to Android Studio 4.1 + Gradle to 6.5. Once you clicked the download button and downloaded the NDK, don't forget to click the "Apply button" to update properly your project. Then click OK.

Comment: In my case, right after installed the NDK (23.1.7779620), I had to add this line `ndk.dir=/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620` to my `local.properties`

Answer (score 6):

1. download NDK in setting, fix that issue.
2. If you cant click Download. manually add this path to your local.properties file

**ndk.dir=/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147**

21.3.6528147 --> version your NDK folder

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to project structure then

[image: Go to project structure then]

Download the the NDK and rebuild the app.

This solution works for me.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Android studio 4.1.1 can not set Android NDK Location on Project Structure,
you need edit `local.properties` file and add

```
ndk.dir=/Users/yourname/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147
```

on `build.gradle` file ndk version is:21.3.6528147

```
ext.versions = [
        'minSdk': 19,
        'targetSdk': 30,
        'compileSdk': 30,
        'kotlin': '1.4.10',
        'buildTools': '30.0.2',
        'ndk': '21.3.6528147'
    ]
```

Answer (score 4):

> **Make sure you have downloaded and installed NDK bundle under Sdk directory. If not open SDK Manager. Install it by checking *NDK(Side
> by side)***

[image: Go to Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System settings -> Android SDK]

> **Restart the IDE and try it again. If further any problem, pls add this code in** ***build.gradle*** file

```
android {
    ........

    defaultConfig {
        .........

        ndkVersion '22.1.7171670' // Your downloaded NDK version
    }
}
```

Note: Keep your ***local.properties*** file like bellow:

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk # My installed SDK location
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

Comment: This worked for me in Linux / Ubuntu with React Native Client

Answer (score 4):

Just *remove or rename* **ndk-bundel** in **Android SDK folder**

Answer (score 3):

```
ndk.dir=c\:\\Users\\DanielWaiguru\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670
```

has been deprecated and the AGP should set the default ndk version but in case it doesn't, specify a specific version of ndk in your build.gradle as follows

```
android {
    ndkVersion <version> 
}
```

for example

```
ndkVersion "22.1.7171670"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Things to be checked if you are facing this error:**

- Check whether Ndk location is specified or not in local.properties file.

If not, go to the NDK location inside your sdk folder,if there are multiple ndk versions delete previous versions if you don't need. Go inside the latest version folder and check whether source.properties file is present or not. Copy the folder path and specify the path in the local.properties file.

For me it is

ndk.dir=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\22.0.6917172

- In app level build.gradle file specify the version number if it is incorrect

For me it is

android {

ndkVersion '22.0.6917172'

}

**Important note:**

The value for ndk.dir should no longer be set in your app's local.properties file, and support for this ndk.dir setting will be removed in a future version. The Android Gradle Plugin sets the NDK version by default, but if you need a specific version of the NDK, you can set android.ndkVersion in build.gradle.

You can visit this official page [for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk)

Answer (score 2):

Just go to:

1. File settings
2. Search for the Android SDK
3. In the SDK tools, locate ndk and tick "show package details."
4. Download the ndk error version displaying on your console.
5. Make sure you've cmake sdk also installed

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and solved it
Go to the Sdk path and then go inside the ndk folder and then cut - paste the folder with the version name somewhere else and then clean and rebuild.

Comment: This worked for me using React-Native-Cli

Answer (score 1):

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 on MacOS 11.1. None of the above solutions worked for me. What worked for me was **not** a reconfiguration of **gradle files** but a simple reconfiguration of the **NDK package**.

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.0.7026061
cp android-ndk-r22/source.properties .
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for this is: for a specific buildToolsVersion, might come with a default ndk version, but this version of ndk might not located under the ndk.dir, so a simple fix would be

```
android {
    ndkVersion <an existing version of ndk>
}
```

Comment: you helped me a lot. I accidentally downloaded half NDK and that was causing problem. just go to /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk and delete NDK bundle folder . ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED react native

> NDK at C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file
```

##### if you are using the react native change ndk version in build.gradle

##### i was changed ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529" to ndkVersion = "22.1.7171670"

Answer (score 1):

Go to build.gradle file paste  ndkVersion "23.1.7779620" in the android section

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"
}

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't really see how this answer adds anything to the many existing answers. Please only post additional answers if you have contents that add value somehow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Me too!
When I upgrade AS4.0.1---->4.1.1

And
project‘s build.gradle

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'`

gradle-wrapper.properties
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip`

I got this problem,And solution is very simple:

I **copy the file to ndk-bundle directory**

DONE

Comment: which file you copied exactly please?

Answer (score 0):

Downloan Ndk https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads
And place in /Users/yourname/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your gradle version to 3.4.2, by adding the following line to your Project's build.grade file,

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

Answer (score 0):

1.First of all make sure you have installed ndk on the android studio sdk manager
2. add the following lines in the local.properties file

`ndk.dir = C:\\Users\\MACOWIGO\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670`

3. then on the build.gradle file add the following line

   `buildscript { ext { buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3" minSdkVersion = 21 compileSdkVersion = 29 targetSdkVersion = 29 ndkVersion = "22.1.7171670" }`

nake sure the ndk version provided on the build.gradle file is the same as the one provided/written in local.properties file

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to local.properties(SDK Locations)
2. Add to NDK Source path

   `ndk.dir=c\:\\Users\\SankA\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670`

[Look Like this Image - Myexample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TVau.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Removing following line from `local.properties` worked for me as mentioned in accepted answer it is deprecated.

```
ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Flutter` projects:

Run the command `flutter clean` in your android studio terminal.

Then add the `ndk` version in the `defaultConfig` in the file at this location: `android > app > build.gradle`,
just like shown below:

```
android{
  defaultConfig {
    ndkVersion = "22.1.7171670"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you really use NDk?

1.If yes you can try above accepted answer and let android studio download latest ndk for you

2.If no then go to NDK folder location /Users/yourname/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/
Delete all folder that start with "ndk" like ndk , ndk-bundle .
Rebuild project

Comment: Because the OP accepted the answer, doesn't that mean that only option1 in your answer is true

Comment: Android studio let you download the latest ndk and that is vry much correct answer and i have tried that too.But my point is if you application uses NDK then only update the NDK otherwise just remove the NDK folders as mentioned in 2nd point. Just randomly downloading latest ndk does not make sense if you really don't use it.

Comment: Downvoting because removing the NDK should not be a recommended solution as it might affect those projects which require the usage of NDK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case running several Flutter builds, it seems I had an older NDK version installed that I no longer needed.  Removing that via SDK Manager fixed the issue

`> NDK at /Users/gene/tools/android-sdk-macosx/ndk/21.1.6352462 did not have a source.properties file`

Trying the answers here to update the SDK, I removed the offending NDK version, with plan to refresh the update. However, after then trying to run the app without bringing back that older NDK, all apps then built successfully

Answer (score 0):

In my case upgrade gradle as follows at gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is funny.

I downloaded `ndkVersion '24.0.8215888'` one minute before, and use it.

Then OK.

Here is in

> /Users/xx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/

[image: 111]

And in `app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    ndkVersion '24.0.8215888'
}
```

And in `gradle/local.properties`

```
ndk.dir=/Users/xx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888
```

---

I tried `NDK 21.1.6352462` a lot,

Not working.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that the ndk version installed has missed source.properties file, SO change ndkVersion on build.gradle onto correctly installed ndk version with that file OR if missing re-install ndk.