# React-Native: ''Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts...''

Tags: android, react-native, maven, build.gradle, jcenter

I'm build my project after added react-native-image-crop-picker. But i meet this error.
[image]
Could you please to show me the way to fix this. Thank you very much.

```
//build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: jcenter message is not the error message, it's just a warning saying you should consider removing jcenter and use maven. The error message you're looking for comes after `* What went wrong:`. And in your case this answer should fix your problem: [NDK at ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372383/ndk-at-library-android-sdk-ndk-bundle-did-not-have-a-source-properties-file)

Comment: Here is a useful link that will provide an alternative solution for addressing this issue.
https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

try this to migrate from jCenter to mavenCentral

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions**

- Migrate your dependency libraries from jcenter to mavenCentral (Find 'jcenter()' and replace it with 'mavenCentral()') raise a pull request (Do this in your free time).
- For quick workaround apply changes to the libraries in your
  node_modules folder and use 'patch-package' library to save and apply
  changes.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and it's work for me

remove yarn.lock , nodeModules , podlockfile , and then yarn install.

thank me latter :)