# Task :app:mergeDevelopmentDebugNativeLibs

Tags: react-native

The error message is .

Task :app:mergeDevelopmentDebugNativeLibs .

More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets,

And i try

```
packagingOptions {

        pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'

        pickFirst '**/libfbjni.so'

    }
```

and run application but app is crash !!

Comment: you will find the solution here ------>^^^
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70060992/react-native-please-remove-usages-of-jcenter-maven-repository-from-your-b

Comment: yes i try this solution but not working .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that works for me :

remove yarn.lock, nodeModules, podlockfile,
and then execute `yarn install`.