# react native ./gradlew bundleRelease not working

Tags: react-native, build, apk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0x1r.png)

i can't build apk and I have this error

Answer (score 0):

Try clean build:

1. Delete node_modules
2. npm cache clean –force
3. npm install
4. cd android
5. gradlew clean
6. gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

if this fails: in root of project:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

You can track this issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28510

Comment: it is still not working, here is another image of my logs, idk if it helps https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/942830353494728766/1021094418104721559/unknown.png

Comment: add ndk in build gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372383/ndk-at-library-android-sdk-ndk-bundle-did-not-have-a-source-properties-file
Also, these seems to be warnings not errors. Can you check if apk is there at android/app/build/outputs/apk/xyz.apk, or android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/xyz.apk

Comment: i did it and still get the error, and by the way there is a message "NDK at C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file" and when I go to that directory there is indeed no source.properties file, idk if it helps https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/942830353494728766/1021431486899048458/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it was because one of my folder had a space and it tryed to run it as a command