# NDK is not installed - A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'

Tags: android, react-native, android-ndk

[image]

Error Log :
[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\Aniket\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file
[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\Aniket\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file

I already have the latest version of NDK but it is not supported.
What did I do to run the react native application.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this issue is due to the version of react-native-animated installed in the project. I have resolved this issue by installing `"react-native-reanimated": "^2.17.0"` this version.

Please note that I got a one time warning, but finally the app started building normally. Here's that warning:

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2TA0.png)

Hope this solution helps.

P.S: I have encountered the similar problem again but with different package this time. I have resolved this with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69823272/19975858)