# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-reanimated

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\muska\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NDK at ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372383/ndk-at-library-android-sdk-ndk-bundle-did-not-have-a-source-properties-file)