# Android NDK location not configurable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ubuntu-18.04

In project settings (File -> Project Structure) 'Android NDK location' field is greyed out:

[image]

Clicking on 'Download Android NDK' briefly displays some dialog. There are several versions of NDK installed:

[image]

**What is wrong with my setup?**

Host: *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*

Android Studio *4.1.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 5, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-128-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.ideolog, org.jetbrains.kotlin
Current Desktop: LXDE*

Submitted [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175980360)

Answer (score 29):

- Leave SDK Location ;) we can still select from **Files> Project
  Structure> Modules> NDK Version**

[image: img1]

- Or, Simply Add

> `ndkVersion '22.0.7026061'`
>
> in build.gradle(app) like this
>
> ```
> externalNativeBuild {
>     ndkBuild {
>         path file('src/main/jni/Android.mk')
>     }
> }
>
> ndkVersion '22.0.7026061' // your desire version
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> }
> ```

[image: img2]

- **Extra Tips:---** you can set path variable here
  [image]
- ### Still App not Building for **NDK** ??

  1. **Close** Android Studio.
  2. Delete **.temp** folder located
     `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` (if exist)
  3. Delete **Options** Folder  located in
     `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\`
  4. Delete **NDK or ndk-bundle** folder located in your SDK directory... `in my case D:\Android\SDK\ndk`
  5. Now clean temps from SDK Manager > **Optimize disk Space** [don't worry it will not delete your essential files] [image]
  6. Now, install your desire NDK version from **SDK Manager**
     [image]

Comment: Thank you, however this workaround does not answer the question

Comment: are you sure you have the exact version of what the project seeking? if not click on the download text may solve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem and by setting NDK value in **local.properties** file of my project, that problem gone

```
ndk.dir=D\:\\mySdkFolder\\sdk\\myNdkFolder
sdk.dir=D\:\\mySdkFolder\\sdk
```

Comment: NDK location field is still greyed out

Comment: @Andriy yeah but the path added in local.properties shows in the ndk location field. so for me I use local.properties to edit the ndk location.

Answer (score 1):

With a project open, click Tools > SDK Manager.

Click the SDK Tools tab.

Select the NDK (Side by side) and CMake checkboxes.