# NDK is not installed

Tags: android, flutter, android-ndk

When building a flutter app, I get an error stating

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:extractReleaseNativeDebugMetadata'.     
> NDK is not installed                                                  
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 822ms
```

However, the android NDK is installed.

Comment: Have you had any luck with answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122903/ndk-is-not-configured-issue-in-android-studio) ?

Comment: Yes; can you write a answer so I can accept it @javdromero?

Comment: It's ok, if an answer from that post worked for you, upvote that one so I don't duplicate an answer just for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that error on React Native 0.64 app on AppCenter build for Android.
The solution is to go to `android/app/build.gradle` file and comment `ndk { debugSymbolLevel 'FULL' }` line if you have so (`defaultConfig { ndk { debugSymbolLevel } }`)

The solution was found by my colleague Jose, so all credits to him)

Comment: im using flutter, but my solution was very similar, so I'll accept this

Comment: Although this solves the error, I don't think its a very good solution to the problem. Having debug symbols is important. How about providing informatino about how to install the missing NDK?

Comment: This is not a solution

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue. I wanted to extract the debug symbols for better debugging in the production environment.

### Solution

##### Step 1: Installing `NDK` and `CMAKE` SDK tool from android studios (You can skip it, if already installed)

Open any project in Android studio. (Doesn't matter which project. We just want to access SDK manager)

1. With a project open, click `Tools > SDK Manager`.
2. Click the SDK Tools tab.
3. Select the NDK (Side by side) and CMake checkboxes.

Image of SDK Manager

[image]

4. Click OK.
5. A dialog box tells you how much space the NDK package consumes on disk.
6. Click OK.
7. When the installation is complete, click Finish.

##### Step 2

###### 1. Check which version of NDK is installed in your system.

To check, find the NDK folder inside the Android SDK folder. For mac users, it is located at - `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/`

You will find a folder with the NDK version name inside this directory.
For example - in my case, the installed NDK version was `23.0.7599858`. So, I was able to find this directory at this location `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/`

*Note: For Ubuntu or windows users `sdk/ndk` directory's location will be different.*

###### 2. Ensure you have the same NDK version mentioned in the `android/build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        ndkVersion = "23.0.7599858"  # the installed version of ndk.
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Make sure you have `ndkVersion` initialized in the `app/build.gradle`
like this:

```
android {
    ...
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    ...
}
```

Or you can also directly write the version here like this:

```
android {
    ...
    ndkVersion "23.0.7599858"
    ...
}
```

You don't have to add the ndkVersion in `android/build.gradle` if you do this.

Comment: @Nailuj29 this seems to be the right answer. Please accept this.

Comment: Specifying the ndkVersion as above didn't work for me. This worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275504/60620

Comment: On Ubuntu my ndk was located here: `~/Android/Sdk/ndk` . You can also check the "Show Package Details" checkbox in the `Tools > SDK Manager` to see the installed version of ndk.

Answer (score 9):

1. **Using android studio open**
   a. Go to settings, System settings, android sdk,on the tabs select SDK Tools confirm if NDK (side by side) and CMake Tool are installed
   b. If not installed check them and press apply to download and install them.[image: SDK TOOLS confir, NDK and CMake]
2. After successfull confirmation. **Open your project android folder** find *local.properties* file, *android/local.properties*. You will find Something like this[image: local.properties file]

**Add your NDK path as follows[image: adding ndk path]**

**To find yoour NDK path**

1. Go to home files if linux, android folder, sdk folder, inside find ndk folder, ie
   */Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888*

Happy Coding ! ! !

Comment: ndk.dir is imp.

Comment: In particular, what helped me the most was the local.properties file that needs to exist.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem and fixed it.
As of 27 March 2023, with the latest Android Studio on Windows 10, follow these steps:

1. You have to install "NDK (Side by side)" option from the SDK manager.
2. Specify ndkVersion in the build.gradle with the full version of NDK that is locally available from your machine. The path is usually

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653

3. Please note that you may still see this error if the project you are working on has the wrong ndkVersion hardcoded. Please correct it, it my case it was

-        ndkVersion '22.0.7026061'
+        ndkVersion '25.2.9519653'

Note:
You may try to do this from File->Project Structure but I would recommend against it. For instance for me even with a successful NDK build with my steps I was getting the Android NDK location blank and the download option downloads an obsolete version of the NDK which does not help.

[image]

You may also try to fix this issue by doing step 1) and then choosing the NDK version from File->Project Structure->Modules but this just tries to automate step 2) but you still have to follow step 3).

[image]

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66527752
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275504

Answer (score 1):

After I added

```
ndk {
    debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
}
```

in app build.gradle file I got this error about NDK not installed.

I resolved the same problem by making this change in main build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
...
    }
```

This Gradle upgrade forced me to upgrade the url in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

I have Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3

Comment: This is the one that did the job for me. It is much better than adding a specific ndk version to build.gradle, which could be really annoying when working in a team.

Answer (score 0):

I have only installed ndk from the android studio and
My problem just got solved, After including ...

### local.properties

`ndk.dir=<ANDROID_SDK>\\ndk\\XX.X.XXXXXXX`

### android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    // ...

    ndkVersion "XX.X.XXXXXXX"
    // ...

    buildTypes{
        release{
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
             }
        }
    }
}
```

This could help someone and save his/her time.

Comment: defining "ndk.dir" is currently deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flutter Please use this approach(according to your ndk version from checkin android studio),
it solved my problem and I used it for debug symbols native crashes

android {
...
ndkVersion "23.0.7599858"
...
}