# facing issue in generating flutter release android build

Tags: android, flutter, dart, release

I am facing issues regarding generating an android release build.

things I have tried:
i have install NDK but it doesn’t work

add this to local.properties as well but didn’t work

> storeFile= C:/users/username/key.jks

[Vs code android release build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKWpk.png)

Comment: Check out the solutions in this topic; https://stackoverflow.com/a/69123361/12206317

Comment: well i find the solution from apple Dev forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687489

Comment: after i follow flutter official apk release build documentation