# Google Play warning: "This APK contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols", but NDK is not installed

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play, build.gradle, apk

I'm having this warning when trying to publish my APK in Google Play:

[image]

I've read here in stackoverflow that the solution is to include in build.gradle's defaultConfig:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.myproject'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    ndk {
        debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
    }
}
```

as mentioned here [Playstore error: App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568757/playstore-error-app-bundle-contains-native-code-and-youve-not-uploaded-debug/64729294#64729294)

My project does not have the NDK installed, so when trying to build with that ndk debugSymbolLevel, it gives me an error.

Is there anyway to remove this Google Play warning without having the NDK installed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98773).

I have tried many methods before. If you want fix this warning, refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778908/8389069).