# How to upload native debug symbols of flutter app to Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: flutter

When I build release of my app, I use following command.

`flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=debug-info/`

So I generate obfuscated appbundle for android. Flutter generates

```
app.android-arm64.symbols
app.android-arm.symbols
app.android-x64.symbols
```

files under `debug-info/` folder. I create a zip file containing 3 files under `debug-info/` folder and I upload this file to App Bundle Explorer at Google Play Developer Console. But Google Play Developer Console shows following error and does not accept this file.

```
The native debug symbols contain an unexpected file: app.android-x64.symbols.
The native debug symbols contain an unexpected file: app.android-arm.symbols.
The native debug symbols contain an unexpected file: app.android-arm64.symbols.
```

How should I upload native debug symbols to Google Play Developer Console?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to zip the symbols files, you have to zip the `[YOUR_PROJECT]\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib` directory.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778908