# How to add NDK with flutter android build using CodeMagic CI/CD Interface?

Tags: android, flutter, cicd, codemagic

I am learning CI/CD Workflows for Flutter apps, I have successfully set up the CI/CD for the flutter android app but it still shows the warning while submitting through CI/CD as follows:

`This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.`

whereas it does not show any warning when I manually build the app and submit it to the play store.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Install the NDK (Side By Side)**

In Android Studio, install the NDK to your Flutter Project by following these steps

- From an open project, select Tools > Android > SDK Manager from the main menu.
- Click the SDK Tools tab.
- Check the box to Show Package Details and note the version number
- Check the box next to NDK, CMake, and Android SDK Command-line Tools
- Click Apply

[Install NDK and CMake in Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd8I4.png)

After the necessary files are installed, go to File > Project Structure > SDK and select the NDK version.
or add this line to your *./android/app/src/build.gradle* file

---

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    ndkVersion "21.1.6352462" // << Add this line with your version of the NDK

    ... 
}
```

---

See [the NDK documentation here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html) for more details on installing the NDK.

**2. CodeMagic Build Settings**
In your Project Set up on codemagic.io make sure you're building for release then try building your app again.

[Under build settings make sure you're building for release and not debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viLjZ.png)

Comment: I have already set to release build but it still shows that native debug symbols are missing in a build.

Answer (score 0):

It's a partial answer. I took the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778908/11959421) and wrote a post-build script. The script, shared below, creates the required debug symbol zip that we can upload manually. I haven't automated the distribution step so I can't say what we need to do there.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
pushd build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib
zip -r $CM_EXPORT_DIR/aab-debug-symbols.zip *
popd
```