# App Bundle contains native code google play warning

Tags: flutter, debugging, warnings, google-play-console, native-code

I got this warning when I was publishing my app

This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend that you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug.

Comment: Hope this help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568757/playstore-error-app-bundle-contains-native-code-and-youve-not-uploaded-debug

Answer (score 0):

**It's just a warning, nothing else. Just go ahead.**

if you want to remove that error then use following details:

1.

```
buildTypes {   release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ndk {
          debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
        }   } }
```

2. 

**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'**