# Debugging MAUI issues from android playstore Crash details stacks

Tags: android, google-play, maui, visual-studio-debugging, callstack

I have a MAUI application available on the playstore.
Google PlayStore has the "Crashes and ANRs" reports.
Because MAUI isn't exactly Java, I'm having a difficult time finding the actual issue from the callstack.

What's the best way to add debugging information or something to better locate the issues with google's reports? Espcially in the ANR section where it seems to look like native stacks.

Ideally I would like to have the line of code where an exception occured, or at least see proper non-native call stacks.
Or alternatively, a way to load the callstack in visual studio to identify the issue.

[image: ANR Issue]

Might be related to this, but I would need a MAUI solution:
[Playstore error: App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568757/playstore-error-app-bundle-contains-native-code-and-youve-not-uploaded-debug?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Comment: Did you read the official document about the [Android vitals](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr)?

Comment: Yes ofcourse ,i know the causes of ANRs. I just need to know where they orginate from. And for that i need debug symbols to be created with my MAUI build, so i can upload it to my track.

Comment: Maui didn't support the playstore native debug symbols, but you can use the appcenter to analize the crash.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Microsoft has officially deprecated App Center. I recommend using Sentry for Analytics + Crash Reporting.